# Check if filed is not 0 then check age - with dateTime - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to check the field if is not like 0,
then I check in the `Where` if the age is larger than today.

The code:

```
select *
from aa
WHERE (datediff(month, dateadd(day,-day(birthDate1)+1,birthDate1),dateadd(day,-day(birthDate1)+1,GETDATE()))>=828.0)
   or (datediff(month, dateadd(day,-day(birthDate2)+1,birthDate2),dateadd(day,-day(birthDate2)+1,GETDATE()))>=828.0)
```

And then there is an exception:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

And if I ask only one question it works well:

```
select *
from aa
WHERE (birthDate1 <> '00000000') and DATEDIFF(YEAR,birthDate1 ,GETDATE())>18
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @Sami - I'm try `int` but its not help

Comment: @GordonLinoff - the type of the fields is: `varchar(2000)`

Comment: You realize that's not a correct way to check the age?  `DATEDIFF(YEAR...` only checks the difference in year, not the month and days.

Comment: @Zorkolot - I need only the Years

Comment: @Ayal You're using in your very own example code- "birthdate" and then today's date with `GETDATE()`.  So you want someone's age in years?  `YEAR` does not do that.  I've told you this and you don't seem to understand.  And that's completely fine if that's what you intended- that just makes it a bad example and I'm calling it out as such in case others are trying to do something with a birthday and `GETDATE()`.

Comment: I'm sorry. Now this is the real code, I need everyone who is older than 69.10 years

Comment: What is 828 days?  You say you're looking for people older than 69.10 years.  This would be approximately 25239 days.

Comment: Can you tell us precisely what you mean by 0.10 years?  In my career I've spent a lot of time working out fractional parts of calendar periods for many customers.  I can tell you that everyone has a different definition.

Comment: I think you may need to delete this question and ask a new one with the suggestions provided in the answers and comments. Just reading through it, I'm not entirely sure of what code you're asking a question about or what you have and haven't attempted. And how exactly do you define .1 years? There is a lot of advice here to help you address the issue you're trying to get help with. Do you have `birthday1` fields with strings not formatted in `YYYYMMDD`? The error you keep referencing seems to indicate yes.

Comment: @Shawn - I have a big problem. Because there are rows whose value is '00000000'

Comment: @Ayal This is one of the problems with storing dates as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(date, birthDate1, 112), GETDATE())
```

The number `112` in `CONVERT` function means that we supply ISO format of date `yyyymmdd`.

[See this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp) for reference.

Your `WHERE` clause should look like this:

```
WHERE ((birthDate1 <> '00000000') and DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(date, birthDate1, 112),GETDATE())>18)
   OR ((birthDate2 <> '00000000') and DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(date, birthDate2, 112),GETDATE())>18)
```

**UPDATE**

You can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN birthDate1 <> '00000000' THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,CONVERT(date, birthDate1, 112),GETDATE()) END Age1,
           CASE WHEN birthDate2 <> '00000000' THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,CONVERT(date, birthDate2, 112),GETDATE()) END Age2
    FROM my_table
) a WHERE Age1 > 838 OR Age2 > 838
```

Comment: Its show me an error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: It still produces an error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: Yes, the format is yyyymmdd. But there are lines whose value is 00000000

Comment: I canot find it, send me a link to the question

Comment: And if I want to add more conditions to the `where`, Where am I add them?

Comment: Yes, Maybe I will ask about 838 months, but can I ask about 69 years and 10 months?

Comment: @Ayal It's better to ask about months 69.10 years = 69*12 + 10 months = 838 months. Try this query: `SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *,
      CASE WHEN birthDate1 <> '00000000' THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,CONVERT(date, birthDate1, 112),GETDATE()) END Age1,
      CASE WHEN birthDate2 <> '00000000' THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,CONVERT(date, birthDate2, 112),GETDATE()) END Age2
  FROM my_table
 ) a WHERE Age1 > 838 OR Age2 > 838` Also, you can see it in my updated answer.

Comment: @Ayal  69.10 years isn't 838 months unless OP has a special definition of .10 where .1 <> 1 tenth. 10 months would be close to .8 years. `DATEDIFF()` returns an `int`, which by definition will always be a whole number. So you can't use `DATEDIFF(year,...)` to get 69.1. You'll have to define what you mean by a .1 year. And Michal is correct, you'd probably be better using `month` instead of `year`, but you could still have a situation where you have x years, x months and 27 days. If you are going March to March, how do you want to calculate that? Dates are always fun. :-/

Comment: @Shawn OP wanted exactly 69 years and 10 months, which is 838 months :) and SQL takes good care of it when using `DATEDIFF(month...`, whihc returns reliable results, so we don't need to worry :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Gotcha. I saw the .10 years and missed how it was defined. The issue seems to have added details across multiple comments.

Comment: And just for future reference, `Age` makes for an excellent computed column. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you storing birthdates as a string?  This is your basic problem.  If you stored the value as a date, then you would not have this problem.

Even if you were storing it as a date, I think the logic you want is to see if someone is 18 today.  Then the logic would be:

```
select *
from aa
where (BirthDate1 <= DATEADD(YEAR, -18, GETDATE()) OR
      (BirthDate2 <= DATEADD(YEAR, -18, GETDATE())
```

This says that the birthday is on or before the equivalent day 18 years ago -- more likely what you want.

`DATEDIFF()` counts the number of year boundaries between two dates.  So, anyone born in 2000 regardless of the date, would return 18 this year.  Or, to phrase it another way, it would return 18 for anyone turning 18 this year.

You can possibly fix your query using `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
select *
from aa
where (TRY_CONVERT(date, BirthDate1) <= DATEADD(YEAR, -18, GETDATE()) OR
      (TRY_CONVERT(date, BirthDate2) <= DATEADD(YEAR, -18, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I canot change the type becouse this table I get from out

Comment: And the second solution is not help me, I get this error: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: I'm sorry. Now this is the real code, I need everyone who is older than 69.10 years

Comment: @Ayal . . . The second version *cannot* generate that error with this code, unless `aa` is a view`.  `TRY_CONVERT()` does not return an error if the conversion fails.  It returns `NULL`.